# Two dimensional repeatable fields in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I want to achieve something like the table in the image below.

[image]

The columns (weight ranges) is custom post type. When I click on add new range a new column will add with the following fields. And it will save as a new post of that custom post type.

There's also "add new city button" which will act like custom field of that custom post type.

And it will be queried on display page.

Comment: The image link is not working

Comment: Hi sorry. I've modified the link.

Comment: [I've wrote some answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1287812+repeatable) regarding this. Please, research and test some code and update your question accordingly.